# How to get the selected format in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want make a button to save a picture in a address that address_txt give it to me, but problem is that address_txt doesn't give selected format to me it just have name. how can I get selected format?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import PIL
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def save_1():
    address_txt = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="save",filetypes = (("All files","*"),("PNG file","*.png"),("JPG file","*.jpg"),("GIF file","*.gif")))
    print(address_txt)

btn_save = Button(root, text="Save",bg = "light blue",
font=("Times New Roman", 17), command=save_1)
btn_save.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can get the file extension from the value returned from `asksaveasfilename()` by using `image_format = os.path.splitext(address_txt)[1]`.

Comment: `Image.save(filename)` will determine the output format based on the file extension of `filename` passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass `typevariable` in `filedialog.asksaveasfilename`.An example below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()

def save_1():
    address_txt = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="save",filetypes = (("Alls","*"),("png","*.png"),("jpg","*.jpg"),("gif","*.gif")), typevariable=extension_name)
    print("The path is:", address_txt)
    print("The extension is:", extension_name.get())

extension_name = StringVar()
btn_save = Button(root, text="Save",bg = "light blue",
font=("Times New Roman", 17), command=save_1)
btn_save.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Example output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you know the extension you can use defaultextension parameter:

```
file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".png", filetypes=(("PNG file", "*.png"),("All Files", "*.*") ))
```

Comment: if i know the extention, I can add the format to end of the string